# PVS Studio not working with MSVS not installed in default location

Tags: pvs-studio

Due to disk size constraints, I installed MSVS 2017 to `D:\Program Files\Visual Studio`.

I then installed PVS-Studio v6.14. When I tried to run it, I get the following error messages:

```
Error was encountered while opening project 'MIDI2LR.vcxproj'.  0
Exception message:   0
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC'.  0
```

It also appears that PVS-Studio did install its extensions into the `D:\Program Files\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\Extensions\3ci0fu2p.p0x` directory, so it appears that the installer found the executable.

How do I point PVS-Studio to the correct directories?

Comment: Hi, @rsjaffe!

First of all, which Visual Studio versions you have installed in your system besides VS2017? Secondly, we will need your project file (vcxproj). You can send it to _support@viva64.com_. 

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, we are talking about  [/Builds/VisualStudio2017/MIDI2LR.vcxproj](https://github.com/rsjaffe/MIDI2LR/blob/develop/Builds/VisualStudio2017/MIDI2LR.vcxproj) from your repository (develop branch). If you're talking about another project, please specify it. The information is based on the analysis of the project I mentioned before.

Does this project compile on your machine? If a project does not compile, PVS-Studio does not guarantee the analysis. Otherwise, the analysis should be performed correctly. I also note that for the compilation you have to have the components `Visual C++ Build Tools 2015` installed (in this context we use the contents of the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC`).

In this case, such behavior occurs because of your project's file structure – the `PlatformToolset` property is set with a value `v140` before the import of Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props, thus this import is performed based on this toolset. This causes MSBuild to use the compiler from `Visual C++ 2015`, and not from `Visual C++ 2017`.

To compile using the compiler from VS2017 (`V141` toolset), you need to modify the project file (see example of a console application project file that is created in Visual Studio 2017). Then the compilation should be done with a correct compiler and the analysis with PVS-Studio performed correctly.

Comment: I had converted the project from v140 to v141 in the build properties dialog, but somehow that didn't change the vcxproj file. The project was building but PVS-Studio wasn't working. Changing the values in vcxproj fixed the problem. PVS-Studio is now working. Thanks.